# How to solve the crashing problems with MacOS Sierra and interpret this log?

Tags: macos, crash, logs, malware

I have a Macbook 5,1, and installed a patched version of MacOS Sierra not long time ago.  If it matters the battery is not original, and the magsafe is also replaced. It also used to crash often with the old magsafe while I connected and disconnected repeatedly, this new magsafe I've soldered recently and I dont if it makes any problems.

But today it crashed twice first time I was working with software. Just now I was only browsing the internet, safe sites that I visit regularly and there is no reason why it should crash but it did. I dont understand much from this log and dont know what I could do to find out the reason it crashes.

From system.log

> Apr 18 22:09:11 myself GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[873]: 2017-04-18 22:09:11.952 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[873/0x7fffb29b03c0] [lvl=2] -[KSAgentApp setupLoggerOutput] Agent settings: KSAgentSettings:0x100206c50 bundleID=com.google.Keystone.Agent lastCheck=2017-04-18 18:08:48 +0000 checkInterval=18000.000000 uiDisplayInterval=604800.000000 sleepInterval=1800.000000 jitterInterval=900 maxRunInterval=0.000000 isConsoleUser=1 ticketStorePath=/Users/myself/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/TicketStore/Keystone.ticketstore runMode=3 daemonUpdateEngineBrokerServiceName=com.google.Keystone.Daemon.UpdateEngine daemonAdministrationServiceName=com.google.Keystone.Daemon.Administration logEverything=0 logBufferSize=2048 alwaysPromptForUpdates=0 productIDToUpdate=(null) lastUIDisplayed=(null) alwaysShowStatusItem=0 updateCheckTag=(null) printResults=NO userInitiated=NO>
>
> Apr 18 22:10:36 myself com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[874]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
>
> Apr 18 22:14:46 myself com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[881]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
>
> ---
>
> Apr 18 22:16:18 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1492542978 0

Comment: So basically you have a MacBook which already showed hardware related crashes in the past and are running Sierra on unsupported hardware and wonder about crashes? Might be difficult to identify the cause, especially if there isn't more information in the logs than what we see in the question.

Comment: What is a 'patched' version of macOS Sierra, may I ask? In any case, the `GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent` message is informational only, and does not represent an error which would lead to a system crash. The `quicklook` message has been around for a few years and represents some lazy programming at Apple. I have hundreds, if not thousands, of identical entries in the logs of the 5 Macs I maintain personally. I've seen no ill effects on these systems. The `BOOT_TIME` message line is also informational. I see nothing in this log to  indicate a problem.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I think I looked at wrong log file. Then I looked at the Diagnostic folder where I found a possible app that caused the crashed and I uninstalled it, but I'm not sure the problem is solved, so I'll leave the topic open for one month maybe.   2 A patched Sierra is supposed to be installed on older Macbooks, despite that officially it is not supported.